# Manga where mc is reincarnated as a young prince coming out of coma

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

Manga where the main character is reincarnated into the body of a young boy or prince who was in a coma. Coming out of the coma, the king/noble, his father, had no faith in him because it was thought the prince/noble was going to die in the coma after months/years past. After the reincarnation process the prince/noble filtered the memories person body he was now in & regained strength in his body. Then, he was sent to a small town to govern it with the expectation he was going to fail. When he arrived, he first helped the soldiers or hunters fight off an attack from monsters & turns the town from being a desert land to fruitful land over time.

Comment: I’m looking to find this manga i did not get to finish it

Comment: Similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246347/isekai-manga-1st-prince-is-abandoned-after-going-in-coma-but-his-soul-returns-f

Comment: It is not max level hero returns

Comment: That's fair. Can you [edit] in the details that don't match?